# Mass Error Checking without Skipping

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I'm dealing with error handling with dictionaries. Is there a slick way to check if each one of these keys is in the dictionary that I'm searching without skipping over them all (by putting them into one try block) if one generates an error?

Obviously I can check for each key one at a time and that works fine, but I'm looking for a nicer/prettier looking way to do it.

Code:

```
try:
    categories = self.getList(dict[categories])
except KeyError:
    print "No categories found!"

try:
    interests = self.getList(dict[interests])
except KeyError:
    print "No interests found!"

try:
    shops_at = self.getList(dict[shops_at])
except KeyError:
    print "No shops_at found!"

try:
    eats_at = self.getList(dict[eats_at])
except KeyError:
    print "No eats_at found!"
```

Comment: Seeing as your error message and dictionary key are the same, you could put the keys in a list and use a for loop...

Comment: You could nest the `try...except` blocks, but that doesn't really reduce your LOC at all. Best to loop over a mapping between keys and error messages.

Comment: So something like 
code
    for key in dict.keys():
        try:
            key = self.getList(dict[key])
        except KeyError:
            print "error"
code

That could work...
(cant figure out how to do code in comments...)

Thanks @EmmettJ.Butler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to duplicate the functionality of the above code with a loop.

```
params = {categories: "categories", interests: "interests",
        shops_at: "shops_at", eats_at: "eats_at"}

for k in params:
    try:
        value = self.getList(dict[k])
    except KeyError:
        print "No %s found!" % params[k]
```